# prove unicity of a linear continous form

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, hahn-banach-theorem

Let H be a Hilbert space and $ u ∈ H$.

Prove there exists a unique continuous linear form $L∈ H^*$ such that:
$||L||_{H^∗} = ||u||_H$ and $<L, u> = ||u||^2_H$

I proved the existence : We can take $<L, x> = ||u||_H||x||_H$, but I don't have a clue about unicity.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not, you did not prove the existence. That is *not* a linear form (unless $u=0$).

Comment: Right @JoséCarlosSantos, my example is wrong